# Edit xml using regular expression in msbuild?

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-buildengine

i am working with msbuild script.i want to  comment particular line using regular expression in msbuild .pls help me to solve this issue??please give one example other than editing version using regular expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using **FileUpdate** [MSBuild Community Tasks](http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/):

> **FileUpdate**
>   Replace text in file(s) using a Regular Expression

```
<ItemGroup>
   <FilesToBeUpdated Include="/Output/test.xml" />
</ItemGroup>

<FileUpdate
   Files="@(FilesToBeUpdated)"
   Regex="..."
   ReplacementText="..." />
```

Comment: suppose i have file test.xml .then i want to comment line "how r u " in that xml.how can i implent this using msbuild?

Comment: @Nithin : you have provide valid regex this is an other question I believe, not MSBuild specific